# looping a shell command in ansible

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to get going with some more advanced Ansible playbooks and have hit a wall.  I'm trying to get Ansible to do what this /bin/bash 'for' loop does;

```
for i in $(</filename.txt);do '/some/command options=1 user=usera server=$i';done
```

filesnames.txt contains 50-100 hostnames.

I can't use jinja templates as the command has to be run, not just the config file updated.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Jeremy

Answer (score 3):

1. you can use jinja templates, but differently
2. your specific code is not doing something that is most advisable
3. for multi-line code you should use `shell` module.

example of multi-code piece of call:

```
- name: run multiline stuff
  shell: |
    for x in "${envvar}"; do
       echo "${x}"
    done
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash
```

note I'm explicitly setting `executable`, which will ensure `bash-isms` would work.

I just used `envvar` **as an example**, of arbitrary environment variable available.

if you need to pass specific env variables, you should use `environment` clause of the call to `shell` module, refer to: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_environment.html

For simple variables you can just use their value in shell: `echo "myvar: {{myvar}}"`

If you wish to use an ansible list/tuple variable inside bash code, you can make it bash variable first. e.g. if you have a list of stuff in `mylist`, you can expand it and assign into a bash array, and then iterate over it. the shell code of the call to `shell` would be:

```
    mylist_for_bash=({{mylist|join(" ")}})
    for myitem in "${mylist_for_bash[@]}"; do
      echo "my current item: ${myitem}"
    done
```

Another approach would be to pass it as string env variable, and convert it into an array later in the code.

> **NOTE:** 
>   of course all this works correctly only with **SPACELESS** values
>   I've never had to pass array with space containing items

Comment: @jeremy-huey, for best practices, use `shellcheck`, e.g. write your scriptlet into a file, and run: `shellcheck myfile.sh`
This will print various warnings on what to do.
https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck

Comment: So then, would `${envvar}` be a list in the ../var dir for the applicable Ansible role?

Comment: @JeremyHuey I just used it as an example, of some environment variable available. if you need to pass specific env variables, you should use `environment` clause of the call to `shell` module, refer to: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_environment.html

Comment: whre can i declare env  envvar

Comment: @spandey this is a very generic question.
Can you be more specific on what will consume this variable, and where you want to produce it?

Comment: Thanks @mvk_il  i have got the answer how to run for loop in shell script when using Ansible